# How to access values from MySQL Table in a matrix pattern?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays

```
Cust_Id    Name      Phone
--------------------------
A001       John      88888
A002       Smith     77777
A003       Stella    66666
```

Currently I'm executing 3 queries like: **SELECT Name, Phone from tablename WHERE Cust_Id = 'A001'**.
and similarly for A002 & A003
The above query would return : $row[Name], $row[Phone].

Is there any way in which I can run a single query and get the results as: $row[A001][Phone] or I could reference the values directly.

The table has more than 3 tuples.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

why not use `IN`

```
SELECT Name, Phone 
FROM   tablename 
WHERE  Cust_Id IN ('A001','A002', 'A003')
```

and which is the same with

```
SELECT Name, Phone 
FROM   tablename 
WHERE  Cust_Id = 'A001' OR
       Cust_ID = 'A002' OR
       Cust_ID = 'A003'
```